# Vimeo API Refused to load the image in android native app

Tags: android, webview, vimeo

I want to load a video from vimeo in a webview, it works but the preview image doesn't load, audio is playing but the screen is blank and I got this error.

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/-5228946977756841864' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https://i.vimeocdn.com

I found solution: below is meta tag

"http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; img-src * data: blob: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'"

but dont know where to put this line in android native .tried in manifest but not working .

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should go as a meta tag in your HTML.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src ..`